# Tensorflow training Layers time computation

Tags: python, parsing, tensorflow, time, profiling

I am trying to retrieve the computation time of different layers from a training step, i have managed to get the training step information with run_meta_data options, i can see the computation time in Tensorboard of each layer. i have parsed the meta data information to json by generating a timeline object. and also i have converted the protobuf inside the events stored by tensorflow. in both cases when i compute the time of a layer(aggregating the duration of nodes in protobuf or json file) are different than the one shown on the graph. am i missing something?

**Update** the protobuf is parsed into a dictionary. nodes are described bellow.

{            "nodeName": "Tower_0/conv1/Conv2D:Conv2D",
            "opEndRelMicros": "585",
            "allEndRelMicros": "585",
            "allStartMicros": "1527330751389528"
          },
          {
            "nodeName": "Tower_0/conv1/Conv2D:Conv2D",
            "opEndRelMicros": "1721",
            "allEndRelMicros": "1721",
            "allStartMicros": "1527330751390116"
          },
          {
            "nodeName": "Tower_0/conv1/Conv2D:Conv2D",
            "opEndRelMicros": "10",
            "allEndRelMicros": "10",
            "allStartMicros": "1527330751391839"
          },
What i have done to get the time is , iterate through the whole file and retrieve the nodes with name matching the layer name, and add the time of opeEndRelMicros. the times are higher in some layers and lower in some layers.

Comment: Yes, you are missing some example code.

Comment: You can use a profiler to see the training time of each layer: https://towardsdatascience.com/howto-profile-tensorflow-1a49fb18073d

Comment: @KathyWu i have managed to extract this information, from this json file, when i search for the time of each layer it doesn't match the one represented in tensorboard. the way i extract this time is by searching for args.name and if it matches the layer i add the duration of that process. 
`if(item['args']['name'].startswith('Tower_0/layer1'))
            dur=dur+item['dur']`